# Using the new Office 365 API Tools Preview and can't get authenticated

Tags: api, office365

I generated an MVC application and added the Connected Service for the Mail APIs.  I verified that the application was registered in Azure AD.  However, every time AuthenticateAsync is called I get a null pointer (Object reference not set to an instance of an object):

Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator();
var authInfo = await authenticator.AuthenticateAsync(ExchangeResourceId);

Anyone know what might be the issue or where to look?

Comment: I'm making this call inside a Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, (on tools preview version 1.1.512) this is the expected behavior in web projects. AuthenticateAsync will return null when there is a pending redirect. If you just ignore the NullReferenceException, you will see your browser redirect to the logon page.

Comment: So in my Controller action method do I have to explicitly redirect the browser to the Office 365 login page?

Comment: Not on tools preview version 1.1.512 - the redirect should happen automatically.